# d3.js choropleth map example error

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to learn to build a choropleth map using an example provided by d3.js.

I keep getting an error: "TypeError: congress.forEach is not a function" when I switch from the .tsv file in the example to a .json file in my version. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var width = 960,
        height = 500;

var path = d3.geo.path();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

var g = svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on("zoom", zoom));

d3.json("us-10m.json", function (error, us) {
    d3.json("https://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/role?current=true", function (error,     congress) {
        var memberId = {};

        congress.forEach(function (d) {  //TypeError:congress.forEach is not a function
            memberId[d.id] = +d.id;
        });

        g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "states")
                .selectAll("path")
                .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return color(memberId[d.id]); // <-C
                });

        g.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
                .attr("class", "states")
                .attr("d", path);
    });
});

function zoom() {
    g.attr("transform", "translate("
            + d3.event.translate
            + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Sorry I didn't put this on jsfiddle but I couldn't connect to .us-10m.json because of a cross domain issue.

Thank you,
Thom

Comment: This is a cross domain issue on your machine just like it is on jsfiddle, which is why `congress` is null (and as a result `forEach` doesn't exist). You can copy a the file into your project directory so that everything is localhost.

Comment: Thank you meetamit. I tried your suggestion but I still receive the same error.

Comment: Did you change `"https://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/role?current=true"` to `"/path/to/local.json"`? What do you see when you look in the dev tools -> network panel?

Comment: I'm able to see the congress.json info in the firebug console. The next line in the console is  "TypeError: congress.forEach is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`congress` is not an Array — it's an Object:

```
{
  meta: {
    limit: 100,
    offset: 0,
    total_count: 540
  },
  objects: [ {...}, {...}, {...}, {...} ]
}
```

Need to iterate over `congress.objects`:

```
congress.objects.forEach(function() {...})
```

Comment: Thank you Amit! Nice observation, the error is gone.